# Apache redirect HTTP to HTTPS Redirect or Rewrite?

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, https, redirect

I have found two way to redirect http to https with apache.
Using Redirect

```
Redirect / https://mydomain/
```

Or Rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://mydomain/$1 [R,L]
```

What are the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official documentation on [When not to use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) lists
[Simple Redirection](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) and also gives your HTTP to HTTPS as an example:

> [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) provides the [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directives, which
> provide a means to redirect one URL to another. This kind of simple
> redirection of one URL, or a class of URLs, to somewhere else, should
> be accomplished using these directives rather than [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).
> `RedirectMatch` allows you to include a regular expression in your
> redirection criteria, providing many of the benefits of using
> `RewriteRule`.
>
> A common use for `RewriteRule` is to redirect an entire class of URLs.
> For example, all URLs in the `/one` directory must be redirected to
> `http://one.example.com/`, or **perhaps all http requests must be
> redirected to https.**
>
> **These situations are better handled by the `Redirect` directive.**

Your `RewriteRule` example might be a necessary hack if one only has access to single configuration section that handles both HTTP and HTTPS. That is common when there are [`.htaccess`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) files involved e.g. on a shared hosting. That is another story; [When (not) to use .htaccess files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when).

Answer (score 1):

They do the same thing. `Redirect` is simpler, easier to read, and doesn't require mod_rewrite, so it's better to use it unless you need something it can't do.